# how to install opendaylight sodium in cent os 7

Tags: sdn, mininet, opendaylight

how to install opendaylight sodium in cent os 7. 
how to get opendaylight web console  UI.

how to deploy a basic SDN setup using mininet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- List item

download rpm package for ODL 
[ODL rpm package](https://cbs.centos.org/repos/nfv7-opendaylight-111-release/x86_64/os/Packages/opendaylight-11.1.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm)

- rpm -ivh your_rpm_package_ver.rpm
- go ODL installed path
- .bin/karaf

after that ODL terminal will be available for to use.

- Press tab for a list of available commands Typing [cmd] --help will
- show help for a specific command. Press ctrl-d or type
- system:shutdown or logout to shutdown OpenDaylight.

to get ODL ui you have to install some karaf features 
Installing and Listing available features

- feature:install
- feature:list
- and more

for more information Please check Documentation
[ODL beginner doc.](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-sodium/getting-started-guide/index.html)